# Github, created new local repo for new work, want to push/merge to online

Tags: git, github

I was working on a online Github repo I created.

I had to go offline for a month, and during this time I thought to redo the repo from scratch. So I created a new local repo on my system using the Windows Github app. Screenshot at bottom.

I now have internet and want to push it to the my online repo. I already did a commit to delete all the files from the online repo. I now need to push my local to the online. Can I do this either with the github app for windows, or with git command line? I was hoping my timeline of commits can be retained.

Here is a screenshot of my windows github app in my local repo:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've made a commit that's deleted all files from your remote repository, and you've got a new local repository with a completely different commit history started from scratch, then why not just force push your new branch to the remote?

First backup your remote master.

```
git checkout -b oldmaster origin/master
git push origin oldmaster
git checkout master
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for this! Is it possible to keep the remote history though? Its not that big a deal but it would be nice. My main concern is to keep the issues topics  etc on Github.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeff! I think this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hi Jeff I got to the `git checkout master` step. So I am in the remote repo named XYZ in my terminal. But now my non-remote repo is a folder on the desktop with same name XYZ. It has a .git folder and everything. Should I cd into that? Then do `git push -f origin master` but how will it know to push that to my remote one?

Comment: After cd'ing into local repo, I tried this: `git push -f origin master remote https://github.com/Noitidart/mlink.git` but it didnt work it gave `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://github.com/Noitidart/mlink.git`

Comment: just `git push -f origin master` no need to add `remote` on the end

Comment: I tried that but it gives me this error - http://i.imgur.com/yoaKLIX.png  :( `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: OK, so what's the output of `git remote -v` from *both* repositories? Let's compare them and make sure they both have the same `origin` remote setup.

Comment: Thanks so so much @Jeff - from the connected to github repo it gives this: `origin  https://github.com/Noitidart/mlink.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Noitidart/mlink.git (push)` but from the local repo it gives nothing: http://i.imgur.com/dHdwMXF.png

Comment: Right, so all you have to do is add the remote to your local repository. `git remote add origin https://github.com/Noitidart/mlink.git` and all your push/pull operations should work.

Comment: Thank you ver very much @Jeff! It worked! The commit history before my first local commit is gone :( but its saved in the other branch. Thanks very much!